# Isolate scope variable is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For some reason I am not able to access my isolate scope variable "index" in my link function. I have tried both `@` and `=` to see if it made any difference and this had no effect, I also tried using a word other than index (in case it was already in use by angular or something) with the same result. Error msg: `ReferenceError: index is not defined`.

directive:

```
var jobernizeDirectives = angular.module('jobernizeDirectives', []);

jobernizeDirectives.directive('viewLargeContent', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            index: '=index' 
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {

            console.log(index);

            function openEditor() {
                console.log(index);

                var main_container = angular.element('.main_container');
                var view_frame = angular.element('.view-frame');

                console.log(ngModel);

                main_container.append('<div class="dimmer"></div>');
                main_container.append(

                        '<div class="large-content' + index + '">'
                    +   '<textarea>' + ngModel.$viewValue + '</textarea>' 
                    +   '<button>Submit Changes</button>'
                    +   '</div>'

                );  

                var dimmer = angular.element('.dimmer');
                var content_container = angular.element('.large-content' + index);      

                // content_container.css({ marginTop: (content_container.height()/-2), width: view_frame.width(), marginLeft: (view_frame.width()/-2) })
                content_container.css({ height: (0.8*main_container.height()), width: view_frame.width(), marginLeft: (view_frame.width()/-2)  })

                content_container.find('button').on('click', function() {
                    var new_content = content_container.find('textarea').get(0).value;

                    ngModel.$setViewValue(new_content);

                    content_container.hide();
                    dimmer.hide();
                });
            }

            // el.on('click', openEditor);
            el.on('click', openEditor);

        }
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="resumesController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <h2>Your Resumes</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Date Added</th>
                        <th>View/Edit Resume</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="resume in resumes">
                        <td>{{ resume.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ resume.category }}</td>
                        <td>{{ resume.date_added }}</td>
                        <td><button index="le" view-large-content data-ng-model="resume.content">View Resume</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {

        function openEditor() {
        }
        return openEditor;

Comment: doesn't work, I should also mention that I also logged the index variable outside of the openEditor function and got the same error

Comment: please, post `resumes` model

Comment: You mean a log of it?

Comment: Where is `el` defined?

Comment: el is the element the with the directive attribute, I believe angular defines it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index is an attribute of you scope object, so you access it like this:

```
scope.index
```

Both '@' or '=' will work, the difference is that '@' will interpolate the value and update the isolated scope when it changes and '=' means Angular should keep the attribute and the isolated scope in sync.
If the variables have the same name you can use the syntactic sugar

```
scope: {
  index: '@' 
},
```

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/iwewub/113/edit) with your code.

Comment: my scope.index is undefined, also I did try simply using '@' before and it failed. Is there anything else you changed to the code that i'm missing?

Comment: also I should note, i used "le" instead of `{{ $index }}` to see if the expression was causing the issue.

Comment: wow okay, working now...not sure what I changed but now scope.index is defined, completely forgot that I had prepend the scope variable with scope...silly me :/