# Isolated scope cannot access variables higher in the scope chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I had found similar questions on SO:

1. [Isolate scope variable is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949336/isolate-scope-variable-is-undefined)
2. [unable to access rootscope var in directive scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895124/unable-to-access-rootscope-var-in-directive-scope)

But mine in particular is a different question by itself.

I have a directive with isolated scope. In its post link function I'm trying to access a variable that happens to be in the root (top most) scope. In my isolated scope I have tried `myVar: '@'` and `myVar: '='` but none of them worked, the myVar is `undefined` in the directive scope. Below is the return statement of my directive:

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: tmpl,

    scope: {
        myVar: '@'
    },

    link: {
        post: function ($scope) {
            // $scope.myVar is undefined
            // $scope.$root.myVar is defined
        }
    }
}
```

In my console I logged the current scope object and I can trace the `$parent` all the way up to the root and see the var is in there, so the var is also accessible through the `$root` of the current scope.

My question is then why doesn't the `'@'` and `'='` work in this case? Is it because the var is defined higher up in the chain other than the immediate parent, or because possibly some parent scope in the middle is itself an isolated scope and breaks the chain of reference to that var?

Comment: How are you assigning myVar in the html template? (BTW, @ assigns the variable to the value of a DOM attribute, that's never going to evaluate to some $scope value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an isolated scope, you are going to want to pass to your directive whatever it is you want it to use for `my-val`.   As a simple example let's say we have this in our html:

```
 <my-test my-var='{{test}}'></my-test>
```

Our main controller is going to have a scope variable named `test`.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'World';
});
```

So, if you notice the directive is setting `my-var` = `{{test}}`.

Now our directive's scope variable of `myVar` will be bound to that value.

```
app.directive('myTest', function()  {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span>{{myVar}}</span>',

    scope: {
        myVar: '@'
    },

    link: {
        post: function (scope) {
            console.log(scope.myVar);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a simple demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/rkbLJ0dJk4OrtyOD3c8w?p=preview

Comment: I see, the crucial part that I was missing was to declare the var in the DOM. I was expecting the directive to directly gain access to its parent scope. Apparently that is not possible, and I don't want to declare that var everywhere since the directive is used in multiple places... I think the best thing I can do is to make a service that provides the directive access to this var.

Comment: It is possible but not with an isolated scope as far as I know.

Comment: Here is an example using the parent scope.  http://plnkr.co/edit/s8dLh4A6dKY19VWg3vlU?p=preview